# Can you use Apache's <If> to conditionally set the Document Root (without using mod_rewrite)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to set Apache's `DocumentRoot` directive inside a `<VirtualHost>` according to whether a particular remote IP address is calling it. I could use mod_rewrite for this but once I've "made the switch" I subsequently have a very complicated .htaccess file in the two destination folders themselves. I figure I need to do this inside httpd.conf. Is there a way to conditionally switch the entire Virtual Host directory based on my IP?

I am close with the following code, but it doesn't change based on my IP.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

   <If "-R '1.2.3.4'">
      Define mydocumentroot "/var/www/just_for_me"
   </If>
   <Else>
     Define mydocumentroot "/var/www/everyone_else"
   </Else>
   
   DocumentRoot ${mydocumentroot}

</VirtualHost>
```

The `DocumentRoot` variable correctly gets set to the `mydocumentroot` variable, but this always evaluates to the `<Else>` clause, no matter what I try.

Thanks!

Comment: No, you need to understand how that configuration is applied. When the http server is started, the DOCUMENT_ROOT is set for that http host. That has nothing to do with requests, so not with a IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After endless experiments and research it seems that doing any kind of switching in httpd.conf or .htaccess is slow and unnecessarily taxing for the server. I ended up working it out using a combination of mod_rewrite and soft links.

Comment: Would still be nice to see the answer instead of "it's not worth it". If you managed to pull it off you should show how it's done and answer the question first. I still like to do it on a local testing server even if it's not viable for production.